# Rails 5 if statement working on show but not working on index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a poll app. Users can vote, but if they have voted already they are not able to vote again.

This is the method voted_for that checks it:

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :vote_options, through: :votes

def voted_for?(poll)
  vote_options.any? {|v| v.poll == poll }
end
end
```

This wworks in my voting form:

polls/_voting_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form' do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'poll[id]', @poll.id %>

  <%= render partial: 'polls/vote_option', collection: @poll.vote_options, as: :option %>

  <% if current_user.voted_for?(@poll) %>
    <p>You have already voted!</p>
  <% else %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Vote', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want too do thee same on index page, which shows list  of polls and a button VOTE for each. I want to show a button VIEW if user already voted that poll.

polls/index.html.erb

```
        <div class="container">

<% content_for(:page_header) {"POLLS"} %>

  <%= render "filter_box" %>

  <% @polls.each do |poll| %>

    <div class="well">

      <div class="row">
        <h4><%= poll.question %>
          <small>(voted:
            <%= poll.votes_summary %>)</small>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><%= 'OPEN' %>
          <p><%= poll.open_date %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><%= 'CLOSE' %>
          <p><%= poll.close_date %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><%= 'DIVISION' %>
          <p><%= poll.division.try(:name) %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <p>
            <% if  current_user.voted_for?(@poll) %>
              <%= link_to 'VIEW', poll_path(poll), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg block' %>

            <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'VOTE', poll_path(poll), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg block' %>
            <% end %>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="btn-group">

            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_poll_path(poll), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', poll_path(poll), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

polls_controller

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @q = Poll.ransack(params[:q])
  @polls = @q.result.order('id ASC')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
  end
  end


  def new
    @poll = Poll.new
      @poll.vote_options.build
  end

  def create
      @poll = Poll.new(poll_params)
      if @poll.save
        flash[:success] = 'Poll was created!'
        redirect_to polls_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

  def edit
  @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

def update
  @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @poll.update_attributes(poll_params)
    flash[:success] = 'Poll was updated!'
    redirect_to polls_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @poll = Poll.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @poll.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'Poll was destroyed!'
  else
    flash[:warning] = 'Error destroying poll...'
  end
  redirect_to polls_path
end

def show
  @poll = Poll.includes(:vote_options).find_by_id(params[:id])
  @vote = Vote.find_by_id(params[:id])

end

  private

  def poll_params
    params.require(:poll).permit(:question, :description, :division_id, :open_date, :close_date, vote_options_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

But if I use this it ignores the first condition and shows VOTE button for all. Even polls I voted already.

How cnn I fix it?

Comment: Add code for index method and other one also that is working.

Comment: How are you paginating the polls? Maybe show more of the index.html.erb to show how you are displaying each poll on the page.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. I have added full index page and polls_controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@poll` is not a defined variable and will be null when used in if statement.

You have `poll` variable. So use `poll` variable in if statement in index.html.erb instead of `@poll`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t post your controller actions, but you probably aren’t assigning `@poll` in your index action.  You probably have something along the lines of `@polls` assigned instead.  In which case, you will need to iterate over `@polls` in your view and run your conditional logic on each member of that collection.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I added rest of index page and polls_controller. If you could help me with more details would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to add @poll = Poll.includes(:vote_options).find_by_id(params[:id])
to polls_controller but that doesn't change the result.